# How to save a webpage by setting preferences in python for webdriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, autoit

I am currently trying to save a webpage as it appears on the website in html format. Approach I am using is prerssing Ctrl + S using autoit. On pressing that save as dialog box appears where I am asked to enter the name of the file to save. This is working fine. However, I want to save the file by pressing Ctrl + S instead of bring the dialog box in front. I read somewhere by using "set_preference" we can do that. CAn someone suggest how to set a preference. Below is the code I am using for Chrome broswer:

```
driver=Webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com/')

autoit.send("{CTRL down}")
autoit.send("{CTRL down}")
autoit.send("{CTRL up}")
autoit.send("C:\\Users\\karanjuneja\\Downloads\\kj\\ABCD.mhtml")
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

Currently I am using the aboved code, however I want that on pressing Ctrl + S it saves the file in the desired location.

Thanks
Karan

Answer (score 1):

Selenium isn't the designed for this, you could either:

Use getHtmlSource and parse the resulting HTML for references to external files, which you can then download and store outside of Selenium.
Use something other than Selenium to download and store an offline version of a website - I'm sure there are plenty of tools that could do this if you do a search. For example WGet can perform a recursive download (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Recursive_download)
Is there any reason you want to use Selenium? Is this part of your testing strategy or are you just wanting to find a tool that will create an offline copy of a page?

Comment: Hi Buddy, i want to download an offline copy of the page, preferably in MHTML format. Used pyautogui. But do you have any other suggestions?